# Make DbDataReader start reading again from the beginning of the result set

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, sqldatareader

How to make `dr.Read();` start reading again from the beginning if a condition is satisfied?

Something like:

```
SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
for(int i=0; dr.Read() ; i++){
    if(condition ){
        //let dr.Read() start reading from the beginning
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataReader` is forward-only.

Comment: Call the method again?

Comment: A data reader is a "fire hose"...as already mentioned..."forward only".  That's why it is lean, it doesn't have to "remember" anything 'before'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't.

The `*DataReader` classes are *forward-only* iterators.

Instead, you can store the results in a `List<T>` (or a `DataTable`)

Answer (score 6):

The only way to restart it is to grab a new reader  with `ExecuteReader()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that by first closing the datareader using `dr.close();`  then initializing it again.

```
If(condition)
{
    dr.close();
    dr=command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Where command is the `MySqlCommand` object.

Comment: This only works on datareaders with one resultset. Multiple resultsets would reoccur.